# Convert Func<dynamic, bool> to Expression<Func<dynamic, bool>>

Tags: c#, linq

I want to send where expression as parameter but I got this error
"An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"
at line of converting Func to   Expression>

```
public List<dynamic> GetBy(Func<dynamic, bool> WhereExpression) 
    {
        try
        {
            Expression<Func<dynamic, bool>> tt = c => WhereExpression(c) ;

            return (from c in DaynamicContext.GetTable(tbl).Cast<dynamic>()
                    where tt
                    select c).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logs.Log(ex);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think the error message says it all - "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation". You just can't do it.

Comment: I don’t see why you would use `Expressinon<…>` in the first place. Can’t you just use the `Func<…>` and then use `where tt(c)`?